# Filtration and martingale

Tags: probability, martingales

Given a probabilistic space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\geqslant 0},P)$. Let $X_n$ be a series of random variables respect to a given filtration, such that $E(X_i)=m \neq 0$, $E(X_i^2) \lt \inf$.  Let's define $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.
Find processes $A_n$, $B_n$ such that $S_n - A_n$ and $(S_n - A_n)^2 - B_n$ were martingales.

I've tried to calculate $S_n - A_n$, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly:

$$\mathbb{E}(S_{n+k}-A_{n+k}|\mathcal{F}_n)=\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^{n+k}X_i|\mathcal{F}_n)-\mathbb{E}(A_{n+k}|\mathcal{F}_n)=$$

$$\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i|\mathcal{F}_n)+\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+k}X_i|\mathcal{F}_n)-\mathbb{E}(A_{n+k}|\mathcal{F}_n)=$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^nX_i+\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+k}X_i)-\mathbb{E}(A_{n+k}|\mathcal{F}_n)=S_n+k\mu-\mathbb{E}(A_{n+k}|\mathcal{F}_n)$$

$$\Rightarrow  A_n=k\mu-\mathbb{E}(A_{n+k}|\mathcal{F}_n)$$

$\Rightarrow  A_n=-\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$, where $\mathbb{E}(Y_n)=-m$

I don't know how to calculate $(S_n - A_n)^2 - B_n$

Comment: Hint: First find and fix $A_n$ such that $S_n-A_n$ is a martingale. Then automatically square of martingale is a submartingal so that you can apply Doob's decomposition theorem to get $B_n$.

Comment: $A_n = n \cdot m$ (?) Then from Doob's decomposition $B_n = \sum{k=1}^nE[(X_k+m)(2S_{k-1}+X_k-2km+m)|F_{k-1}] (?) I don't know how to continue from this equation.